# SQL Server stored procedure update else insert

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Does anyone know how I can update a row if row exists, else insert statement in a stored procedure?

I try multiple ansvers on google, but cannot get it to work.

My SQL Server stored procedure:

```
USE [mydb]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Sp_Insert_Rapport]
    (@P_STDDetails As Insert_Rapport Readonly)
AS
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO tblRapporter(fldCompanyID, fldMalerID, fldGodkendelsesTidspunkt, fldRapportNoegle, fldRapportVkCvrNr, fldRapportVkNr, fldRegNr, fldStatus)
         SELECT
             fldCompanyID, fldMalerID, fldGodkendelsesTidspunkt,
             fldRapportNoegle, fldRapportVkCvrNr, fldRapportVkNr,
             fldRegNr, fldStatus 
         FROM
             @P_STDDetails
END
```

If I use

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: What is the primary key?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: fldCompanyID så where clause is where = fldCompanyID

Comment: Thanks for input @marc_s , i will keep that in mind

Comment: Look into using a `MERGE` statement.

Comment: does this look right merge P_STDDetails AS Target
USING (Select fldCompanyID,fldMalerID,fldGodkendelsesTidspunkt,fldRapportNoegle,fldRapportVkCvrNr,fldRapportVkNr,fldRegNr,fldStatus From P_STDDetails)
 as Source (fldCompanyID,fldMalerID,fldGodkendelsesTidspunkt,fldRapportNoegle,fldRapportVkCvrNr,fldRapportVkNr,fldRegNr,fldStatus)

Comment: Merge, please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Comment: i say thanks i got this to work, with merge :)